# select the lower number of a row (matlab)

Tags: matlab

With any given matrix, how do you select the lower number in each row? I have something like this so far:

```
matrix = magic (5);
rc = size (mat);
r = rc (1);

for i = 1:r
    disp (matrix (i,:))
```

Comment: If you want the minimum of each row: `min(matrix,[],2)`

Comment: Thank you! What if I want the minimum that is greater than 0?

Comment: `min(matrix(matrix>0),[],2)`

Answer (score 0):

To get the minimum number greater than 0 within each row (according to comments): replace non-positive numbers by `NaN` and then minimize along each row:

```
matrix = randn(5,6); %// example data
matrix2 = matrix; %// copy of data
matrix2(matrix2<=0) = NaN; %// replace non-positive values by NaN
m = min(matrix2,[],2); %// minimize along each row
```